# Chutes and Ladders

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

I am trying to make a Chutes and Ladders style game. I have managed to piece together a board, but I plan to change the location of squares, ladders, and slides for future boards. The ladder is a particularly ugly hack that was adjusted by trial and error. I would be grateful for any advice on building such a board. Specifically I would like to make a command that draws each ladder by specifying the beginning and ending coordinates. I haven't been able to find any decorations that would help in drawing a ladder.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
%board
\draw (0,0) grid (6,1) (5,0)grid (6,3) (0,2)grid (6,3) 
(0,2) grid (1,5) (0,4) grid (6,5)(5,5) grid (6,9) 
(0,8) grid (6,9) (0,6) grid (1,8) (1,6) grid (4,7);

%ladders
\draw[scale=.5,xshift=2.5cm,yshift=1.5cm,rotate=-45] (0,-.5) grid ++(1,6);
\draw[scale=.5,xshift=6.5cm,yshift=9.5cm,rotate=-45] (0,-.5) grid ++(1,6);
\draw[scale=.5,xshift=.5cm,yshift=9.5cm,rotate=0] (0,-.5) grid ++(1,4);

% slides
\draw (1.75,2.5) sin ++(1,-1) cos ++(1,-1);
\draw (1.25,2.5) sin ++(1,-1) cos ++(1,-1);
\draw (5.75,4.5) sin ++(-.5,-1) cos ++(-.5,-1);
\draw (5.25,4.5) sin ++(-.5,-1) cos ++(-.5,-1);

\draw (3.5,6.5) node{$\star$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Chutes and Ladders Board]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*(there are four successive versions.)*

## 1- Semi-Automatic Version

Here is a first attempt via `markings`. Board and ladders are drawing using integer coordinates of cells. But you have to find/specify manually the correct number of bars of each ladder.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\def\ladderwidth{1.5mm}
\def\ladderstep{3mm}
\tikzset{
  board/.style={decorate,decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm with
      {\draw[fill=lime!20] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);}
    },
  },
  ladder/.style={decorate,decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions {1/#1/2} and {-1/#1/2} step {1/#1} with {
        \draw[thick,orange]
        (0,-\ladderwidth) -- (0,\ladderwidth)
        (\ladderstep,-\ladderwidth) -- (-\ladderstep,-\ladderwidth)
        (\ladderstep,\ladderwidth) -- (-\ladderstep,\ladderwidth);
      }
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[board]
  (1,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,4) -- (6,4) -- (6,8) -- (1,8) -- (1,6) -- (4,6);
  \draw[ladder=5] (1,4) -- (1,6);
  \draw[ladder=6] (1,0) -- (3,2);
  \draw[ladder=7] (5,4) -- (6,7);
  \draw[ladder=18] (5,0) -- (2,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## 2- Automatic Version

Here is a second attempt with automatic calculation (via a `to` path) of number of bars for each ladder... The two images show the result with different values of `\ladderstep` (1.5mm on the left and 3mm on the right).

1.5mm [image]  3mm   [image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\def\ladderwidth{1.5mm}
\def\ladderstep{1.5mm}
\tikzset{
  board/.style={decorate,decoration={
      markings, mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm with
      {\draw[fill=lime!20] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);}
    },
  },
  ladder/.style={decorate,decoration={
      markings, mark=between positions {1/#1/2} and {-1/#1/2} step {1/#1} with {
        \draw[thick,orange] (0,-\ladderwidth) -- (0,\ladderwidth)
        (\ladderstep,-\ladderwidth) -- (-\ladderstep,-\ladderwidth)
        (\ladderstep,\ladderwidth) -- (-\ladderstep,\ladderwidth);
      }
    },
  },
  ladder auto/.style={to path={
      let \p1=($(\tikztostart) - (\tikztotarget)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\bars}{int(\n1/\ladderstep/2)+1}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[ladder=\bars] (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[board] (1,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,4) -- (6,4)
  -- (6,8) -- (1,8) -- (1,6) -- (4,6);
  \draw (1,4) to[ladder auto] (1,6) (1,0) to[ladder auto] (3,2)
  (5,4) to[ladder auto] (6,7) (5,0) to[ladder auto] (2,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## 3- Complete Automatic Version

Here is a third attempt. I added the chutes (always via a `to` path).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\def\ladderwidth{1.5mm}
\def\ladderstep{1.5mm}
\tikzset{
  board/.style={decorate,decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm with
      {\draw[fill=lime!20] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);}
    },
  },
  ladder/.style={decorate,decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions {1/#1/2} and {-1/#1/2} step {1/#1} with {
        \draw[thick,orange]
        (0,-\ladderwidth) -- (0,\ladderwidth)
        (\ladderstep,-\ladderwidth) -- (-\ladderstep,-\ladderwidth)
        (\ladderstep,\ladderwidth) -- (-\ladderstep,\ladderwidth);
      },
    },
  },
  ladder auto/.style={
    to path={
      let
      \p1=($(\tikztostart) - (\tikztotarget)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\bars}{int(\n1/\ladderstep/2)+1}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[ladder=\bars] (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    },
  },
  chute auto/.style={
    to path={
      let
      \p1=([xshift=\ladderwidth]\tikztostart),
      \p2=([xshift=-\ladderwidth]\tikztostart),
      \p3=([xshift=\ladderwidth]\tikztotarget),
      \p4=([xshift=-\ladderwidth]\tikztotarget),
      \p5=($(\p1)!.5!(\p3)$),
      \p6=($(\p2)!.5!(\p4)$)
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \path[thick,draw=orange]
        (\p1) sin (\p5) cos (\p3)
        (\p4) sin (\p6) cos (\p2);
        \fill[fill=orange!20]
        (\p1) sin (\p5) cos (\p3) --
        (\p4) sin (\p6) cos (\p2) -- cycle;
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[board] (1,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,4) -- (6,4)
  -- (6,8) -- (1,8) -- (1,6) -- (4,6);
  \draw[chute auto] (1,2) to (3,0) (2,4) to (5,2) (5,8) to (2,2);
  \draw[ladder auto] (1,4) to (1,6) (1,0) to (3,2)
  (5,4) to (6,7) (5,0) to (2,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## 4- Complete Automatic Version with Styles, Scale and Variants

Here is a fourth attempt with scale feature as requested... but without `scale` option. Changes:

- You can choose the global size via `\cellsize`: each `... auto` style takes into account the `\cellsize` distance and changes the coordinate system to keep integer coordinates at center of cells.
- There are three new styles to choose drawing and filling options: `cell`, `ladder` and `chute`.
- There is a new `ladder auto bis` style to draw horizontal bars on ladders.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cellsize}{1cm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ladderstep}{\cellsize/6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ladderwidth}{\cellsize/6}
\tikzset{
  % styles to draw and to fill
  cell/.style={
    draw=green!50!black,top color=lime!10,bottom color=lime,
    line width=1pt,
    rounded corners=\cellsize/5
  },
  ladder/.style={
    draw=orange,line cap=round,line join=round,line width=2pt,
  },
  chute/.style={
    top color=blue!30,
    bottom color=blue!30,
    middle color=blue!5,
    draw=blue!50!black,line cap=round,
    line join=round,line width=1pt,
  },
  % styles to draw board, ladders and chutes
  board auto/.style={
    x=\cellsize pt,
    y=\cellsize pt,
    decorate,decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \cellsize pt with
      {\path[cell] (-.5*\cellsize pt,-.5*\cellsize pt)
        rectangle (.5*\cellsize pt,.5*\cellsize pt);}
    },
  },
  ladder draw/.style={
    decorate,decoration={
      markings,
      mark=between positions {1/#1/2} and {-1/#1/2} step {1/#1} with {
        \path[ladder]
        (0,-\ladderwidth pt) -- (0,\ladderwidth pt)
        (\ladderstep pt,-\ladderwidth pt) -- (-\ladderstep pt,-\ladderwidth pt)
        (\ladderstep pt,\ladderwidth pt) -- (-\ladderstep pt,\ladderwidth pt);
      },
    },
  },
  ladder auto/.style={
    x=\cellsize pt,
    y=\cellsize pt,
    to path={
      let
      \p1=($(\tikztostart) - (\tikztotarget)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\bars}{int(\n1/\ladderstep/2)+1}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[ladder draw=\bars] (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    },
  },
  ladder auto bis/.style={
    x=\cellsize pt,
    y=\cellsize pt,
    to path={
      let
      \p1=(\tikztostart),
      \p2=(\tikztotarget),
      \p3=($(\tikztostart) - (\tikztotarget)$),
      \p4=([xshift=-\ladderwidth pt]\p1),
      \p5=([xshift=-\ladderwidth pt]\p2),
      \p6=([xshift=\ladderwidth pt]\p1),
      \p7=([xshift=\ladderwidth pt]\p2),
      \n1={veclen(\x3,\y3)}
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\bars}{int(\n1/\ladderstep/2)+1}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \path[ladder] (\p4) -- (\p5);
        \path[ladder] (\p6) -- (\p7)
        \foreach \bar in {1,...,\bars}{
          \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\pos}{1/(\bars+1)*\bar}}
          coordinate[pos=\pos] (p\bar)
        };
        \foreach \bar in {1,...,\bars}{
          \path[ladder] (p\bar) -- ++(-2*\ladderwidth pt,0);
        }
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    },
  },
  chute auto/.style={
    x=\cellsize pt,
    y=\cellsize pt,
    to path={
      let
      \p1=([xshift=\ladderwidth pt]\tikztostart),
      \p2=([xshift=-\ladderwidth pt]\tikztostart),
      \p3=([xshift=\ladderwidth pt]\tikztotarget),
      \p4=([xshift=-\ladderwidth pt]\tikztotarget),
      \p5=($(\p1)!.5!(\p3)$),
      \p6=($(\p2)!.5!(\p4)$)
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \path[chute]
        (\p1) sin (\p5) cos (\p3) --
        (\p4) sin (\p6) cos (\p2) -- cycle;
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[board auto] (1,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,4) -- (6,4)
  -- (6,8) -- (1,8) -- (1,6) -- (4,6);
  \draw[chute auto] (1,2) to (3,0) (2,4) to (5,2) (5,8) to (2,2);
  \draw[ladder auto bis] (1,4) to (1,6) (1,0) to (3,2)
  (5,4) to (6,7) (5,0) to (2,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: These solutions are brilliant. I love that the whole thing can be done by specifying paths with a predefined style. This is better than I had hoped for. I was totally unfamiliar with markings prior to your answer. Is it possible to make the board and ladder styles compatible with scaling? For example, if I add [scale=1.5] to the tikzpicture environment, the picture comes out wrong. Perhaps decorations don't scale the way I had hoped.

Comment: @Serge I don't like the `scale` option... I prefer to use a macro to define the reference distance (my fourth and last attempt).